# Can you use a button for stepping through clock cycles on a 65C02?

Tags: clock, microprocessor

this may sound like a stupid question, but I'm working on the 6502 computer project by Ben Eater, and I do not have the clock module. If I just want to step through each individual clock pulse, could I use a button? The datasheet doesn't state that it needs a constant oscillation, but I just want to be sure.

And if I *can* use a button, does it need any extra components to not ruin the 6502?

Thanks.

Comment: Remember to consider switch bounce.

Comment: It depends on exactly how you have implemented the 6502. Is your implementation fully static?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson what do you mean by "static"? Right now the 6502 just has some pins tied high or low, with the address lines connected to an Arduino Mega. You can see episode 1 of the tutorial for more detail.

Comment: @jort57 a "static" CPU design uses static logic, which means that it can handle the clock not changing for long periods of time. The alternative is dynamic logic, which has gates that depend on capacitance to do the right thing, and will totally break if the clock is held in one state for too long. Many CPU designs have dynamic portions.

Comment: i doubt that the 6502 would be ruined if the clock input is held at a steady state ... why don't you just go ahead and try it

Comment: actually, the datasheets are very clear about the required clock inputs ... there is a requirement for fairly fast rise/fall times ... you could not connect the clock to a switch directly ... the output of a flipflop could be used

Comment: look at figure 5 at https://www.eng.auburn.edu/~niuguof/2210labdev/html/_downloads/86fd1dd2291900c88ce7abc0098446fd/ELEC2210%20Expt5.pdf

Comment: @jsotola Would a simple capacitor debouncer like [this](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fecee.colorado.edu%2F~mathys%2Fecen1400%2Flabs%2Flab09%2FSwitchDebounce_013.png&f=1&nofb=1) work?

Comment: read the datasheet about the clock line rise and fall requirement

Comment: As something simpler, could I use a 555 timer oscillator?

Comment: @jsotola it won't be "ruined", it just won't work. The CPU would go into reset or have lots of glitches. As soon as you gave it a fast enough clock, it would work fine again.

Answer (score 2):

You mention 65**C**02 in your title, so there's a good chance it can be done. From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WDC_65C02):<sup>1</sup>

> The W65C02S–14 is the production version as of 2020, and is available in PDIP, PLCC and QFP packages. ... The "S" designation indicates that the part has a fully static core, a feature that allows Ø2 to be slowed down or fully stopped in either the high or low state with no loss of data.

Note that the original NMOS 6502 and many other variants use dynamic logic internally, which means that there's a minimum clock frequency as well as a maximum frequency.

As mentioned in a comment, you'll need to debounce any mechanical switch to guarantee that you get only one clock edge per press. An SPDT switch and a pair of cross-coupled NAND gates is one easy way to make that happen.

---

<sup>1</sup> Also see p. 5 of Western Design Center's [W65C02S datasheet](https://www.westerndesigncenter.com/wdc/documentation/w65c02s.pdf).

Comment: Also see p. 5 of https://www.westerndesigncenter.com/wdc/documentation/w65c02s.pdf where it says "Features of the W65C02S ... * Fully static circuitry ..."

Answer (score 0):

Driving the cpu clock of a 6502 manually with a button won't work on many 6502 versions. Only those with static core will work.

In case you proceed with a static cpu, debounce the inputs accordingly to eliminate the noise in the line.

Otherwise, if you were seeking for a simple clock you could use a 555 or similar in astable configuration although the frequency woudn't be as high as the majority of crystal oscillators in use can provide. On the other hand, if you go this way a 556 could be used with one timer in astable mode for the clock and the other in monostable for the reset input.

On the other hand, if what you need is not a break every clock cycle but every instruction cycle, I would recommend using the RDY pin to halt the processor.